# Outlet not working Properly

Tags: wiring, receptacle, gfci

I decided to put a GFCI outlet in my kitchen. It's an old house and only had 2 duplex outlets in the kitchen. I wired the GFCI making sure I used the correct wire terminals. I left the other terminals taped until I was done. The outlet works fine. Since I only had 2 duplex outlets I decided to add a couple outlets to the GFCI so they would be protected. The second outlet only the bottom half of the duplex outlet worked. And the 3rd had no power at all. The checked the wiring, then decided to use a different duplex outlet in case the other was bad. I got the same result. Only the bottom half of the duplex outlet works and still nothing on the third, while the GFCI still works correctly. What would cause only half the outlet to work? The strange part is the half that doesn't work is the half that the wiring coming from the GFCI.

Comment: Did you break the tabs off the duplex outlet you installed?

Comment: Are these used receptacles or brand new?

Comment: Some clear, focused pics of the wiring on the GFCI and the downstream outlets would be helpful. Turn the power back off before taking them, of course